# Ng Zorro antd style does not take effect

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

Ng Zorro antd style does not take effect
[image: style.less]

[image: angular.json]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your imports to:

```
@import "~ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.compact.css";
```

Comment: I try this, but it will report an error